# Intellij IDEA adds quotation marks on auto completion in SQL?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, autocomplete

if I try to use auto completion in SQL files, any added table or function is enclosed in quotation marks.

This

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
```

ends up as

```
SELECT *
FROM "table1"
```

if I try to use CTRL+Space to autocomplete.

I just can't find that option, which does this and it's really annoying.

Comment: What is the database? Check that the File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | SQL -> **Identifier quotation** is **not** set to "Quote". Also try latest version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.3+EAP Related issue has been addressed there.

Comment: The database is Oracle 12.2 and the mentioned setting is set to "Unchanged". I ran an update and the issue is fixed. Thank you for this hint!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to a setting, but a bug in the software, which is resolved in the most current version (2017.3.3) of IntelliJ IDEA.